# Python script to map SNP to CDS

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to make a program that will identify [CDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_region#Coding_sequence_annotation) containing [SNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism). It populates two dictionaries from two files, one containing the SNP and the other a [GFF3](http://gmod.org/wiki/GFF3) file. One of the dicts populated from the GFF3 file contains the CDS names and the positions of these as tuples.

An example:

```py
cds_pos = {'PRELSG_0019500_6': ('2091320', '2092988'), 'PRELSG_1338600_3': ('1542760','1542853'), 'PRELSG_0013000_1': ('1275531', '1275568')}
```

The other dict contains the chromosomes and the positions for the SNP's as set, such as.

```py
chrom_pos = {'PRELSG_13_v1': {'272093', '964287', '844454', '65770', '336211', '36660'}, 'PRELSG_12_v1': {'1270177', '1368630'}}
```

My idea is to iterate over the two dicts and carry out a pairwise comparison and see if the SNP positions are found in the interval of the CDS. I tried the code below but it didn't seem to work.

```
for chrom, snp_pos in chrom_pos.items():
    for cds, pos in cds_pos.items():
            if pos[0] <= str(snp_pos) <= pos[1]:
                print(cds)
                print(snp_pos)
```

To things I found not to be working. First of all nothing satisfies the interval if statement. Secondly since the position of the SNP can be found on several chromosomes, this needs to be taken into account, which I tried with the chrom == gene statement. This doesn't seem to work though.

Would be happy for any thoughts and comments on have to proceed. Thanks

Edit:

So far my script looks like:

```
cds_snp = defaultdict(set)
for chrom, snp_pos in chrom_pos.items():
        for cds, pos in cds_pos.items():
            ed_chrom = chrom[:9]
            ed_cds = cds[:9]
            if ed_cds == ed_chrom:
                for i in snp_pos: # Iterate through the set of snp positions
                    if int(pos[0]) <= int(i) <= int(pos[1]):
                        cds_snp[cds].add(i)

for i,j in sorted(cds_snp.items()):
    print(i)
    print('\n'.join(j))
```

I have to find a way to evaluate whether the output is correct but it seems plausible.

Comment: It might be a better idea to look if you can apply tools such as bedtools or pybedtools here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues that need to be addressed in order for you to get this code working:

> since the position of the SNP can be found on several chromosomes, this needs to be taken into account, which I tried with the chrom == gene statement.

You are trying to link SNPs with Positions in a CDS. However, you don't seem to have chromosomes for the CDS positions (just names). From the example you posted, your CDS Names are `'PRELSG_0019500_6', 'PRELSG_1338600_3', 'PRELSG_0013000_1'` and your chromosome names are `'PRELSG_10_v1', 'PRELSG_12_v1'`. Ther are no cases where these match up, and to be honest they look like they have different formats, and that you will never have a case where `chrom == gene`

Is there some identifying information in the CDS name that might tell you what chromosome it is on? If there is, you could extract the chromosome number from the chromosome name (i.e. 12 from 'PRELSG_12_v1') and compare this against the extracted chromosome number from the CDS name.

> nothing satisfy the interval if statement

By this I assume you mean the line `if pos[0] <= str(snp_pos) <= pos[1]:`

There is a simple explanation for why this isn't working. When you first extract features from the dictionary as so:

```
for chrom, snp_pos in chrom_pos.items():
    for gene, pos in gene_pos.items():
```

you extract `snp_pos`. This isn't an individual position, but rather is a set of positions. To iterate over individual positions you could add another loop:

```
for snpPos in snp_pos:
```

Finally, for correctness sake, it would be best to keep your interval statement as integers. i.e. write this as

```
if int(pos[0]) <= int(snpPos) <= int(pos[1]):
```

Comment: I have made an edit in my question regarding the issue of CDS names not matching chromosomes name. Using slice indices to get the characters from the beginning until positions 9.  In think this could work as the two first digits of the CDS name corresponds to the chromosome.

Comment: Yes, that should work. But please see my other comments in the answer regarding how you use `snp_pos` (this is a set, not a single string) and how you compare less than/greater than indices.

Comment: I have made an update to my script incorporating some of your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe oversimplifying your problem.

We could download all CDS regions using `mysql` or UCSC table browser, see [this example post](https://www.biostars.org/p/66380/).

Then use bedtools to [merge on overlap](http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/merge.html) with SNP bed file.

Comment: That might be a solution but prefer to try to solve this question in Python.